# Adicionar um título a tag SELECT (sem a opção "selected disabled") sem que ele apareça nas opções?

Tags: html, html-select, placeholder

Como adiciono um titulo ao `select` que ele apareça nas opções e suma quando for selecionar?

Sei que parece que é uma duplicada, mas o problema é que não encontrei o que gostaria exatamente,  a opção `selected disabled` funciona mas não cumpre o que quero. Utilizando o mesmo um exemplo que vi aqui no **stackoverflow** com `selected disabled`  :

```html
<select>
  <option disabled selected>- Selecione -</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Mercedes Bens</option>
</select>
```

Porém, o que gostaria de fazer é que o título *"- Selecione -"* ficasse como a propriedade `placeholder` e quando eu fosse selecionar o campo *"- Selecione -"* o mesmo não aparecesse nas opções e sumisse. Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Consegui "ocultar" as opções com disabled mas não surtiu o mesmo efeito do seu print, para a opção padrão. Veja se te ajuda: `select:focus > option:disabled {display:none;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc também consegue ocultar essa opção com algumas regras em CSS se preferir.

Pensando na experiencia do usuário (UX) e **se o campo não for obrigatório** no caso do usuário mudar de ideia ele ainda deve ter a opção de desmarcar a opção que escolheu, por isso acredito que nesse caso a opção deve constar dentro do campo!

Para isso eu faria desse jeito:

```css
select option[data-default] {
  color: #999; /* cor simulando que o campo está desabilitado depois que abre o select */
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option selected data-default>- Selecione -</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Mercedes Bens</option>
</select>
```

---

Mas se vc realmente que "sumir" como o "label" aqui tem uma opção mesclando o que vc fez com CSS simulando um Placerholder. ***Só que nessa opção o usuário não pode voltar atras, uma vez o campo selecionado ele não tem a opção de desmarcar.***

```css
select:required:invalid {
  color: gray;
}
option[value=""][disabled] {
  display: none;
}
option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>- Selecione -</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes Bens</option>
</select>
```

Nassa resposta do StackOverflow gringo tem mais informações e variações. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805059/how-do-i-make-a-placeholder-for-a-select-box

Comment: hugocsl realmente no meu caso o campo não é obrigatório então vou mesclar suas duas respostas, muito obrigado! Pax!

Comment: @vulgogandini legal! Lembre-se de sempre levar em consideração o UX nesses casos, pois ele pode abandonar o formulário ou desistir da compra por exemplo se não tiver controle total do que está fazendo. Boa sorte com o projeto []´s

Answer (score 2):

Penso que o que você quer seja isso:

```html
<select>
  <option selected hidden >- Selecione -</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Mercedes Bens</option>
</select>
```

Para fazer isso adicione "hidden" na option do selecione!

Comment: Muito legal. Quando vi a pergunta logo esperei por uma resposta com jQuery. :o

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o mesmo efeito da sua imagem utilizando *javascript* para alterar o texto da opção que está selecionada e desabiltada.

Utilizei o *css* abaixo para ocultar as opções desabilitadas quando o `select` estiver expandido:

```
select:focus > option:disabled {display:none;}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var select = document.getElementById("teste");

select.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var options = this.options
    for(i=0;i<options.length;i++){
      if(options[i].disabled && options[i].selected )
        options[i].text="";
    }
});
```

```css
select:focus > option:disabled {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<select id="teste">
  <option disabled selected>- Selecione -</option>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Mercedes Bens</option>
</select>
```