# Esconder opção do select quando ela for igual a opção já escolhida

Tags: html, angular

Tenho um select que possui duas options:

Tamanho, Cor.

Quando eu seleciono Tamanho, ao clicar novamente no meu select, ainda mostra como opção o Tamanho.

Gostaria de retirar ele e deixar disponivel apenas o outro, pois esse já foi selecionado.

Tentei essa lógica:

```
<select [class.disabled]="loadingcadastro" (change)="getIdTipoVariacao(item.value.tipo)"
  formControlName="tipo" class="browser-default custom-select">
  <option class="dropdown-item" selected>{{item.value.tipo || 'Tipo da Variação'}}</option>
  <option [hidden]="item.value.tipo === tipoVariacao.valor" *ngFor="let tipoVariacao of tiposvariacoes;let j = index"
  class="dropdown-item">{{tipoVariacao.valor}}</option>
</select>
```

[image: Deve-se aparecer apenas a opcao "Cor", pois a tamanho já está selecionada.]

Comment: O primeiro `<option>` exibe sempre a opção selecionada. Ele sempre estará visível também. Isto é, se quer ocultar o valor selecionado, você deve remover a opção que possui `selected`.

Comment: retirei a select e coloquei a label com o {{item.value.tipo || 'Tipo da Variação'}}, você acha que esteticamente fica melhor assim ou antigamente?

Comment: Eu não vejo pontos ruins em exibir sempre todas as opções, incluindo a já selecionada. Se ele selecionar a mesma, nada muda. Porém, ocultando a selecionada, vejo a possibilidade de confundir o usuário. Ao selecionar "trabalho" e clicar novamente, aparecendo apenas "cor" o usuário poderá se sentir obrigado a selecionar "cor" achando que, por algum motivo, "trabalho" não está mais possível. Sem contar que é mais intuitivo sempre ter a amostra atual junto com as restantes para se fazer uma comparação. Por questões de UX, eu deixaria exibindo.

Comment: ok, vou voltar como estava

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss concordo com vc! Eu vejo o "componente" assim, vc tem uma caixa com o item selecionado, e uma lista de options, acredito que o certo não é remover nada que esteja na lista de opções, por removendo o item da lista o usuário pode achar que não será possível seleciona-lo novamente... Renaot PLS Aqui tem umas opções para trabalhar com o `select` que podem te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288517/adicionar-um-t%C3%ADtulo-a-tag-select-sem-a-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-selected-disabled-sem-que-ele-a/288523#288523